# Apple Script error 609 with email export to Excel

Tags: excel, email, applescript, analytics

I am interested in doing some basic data analysis on my emails using Excel. After struggling to find a way to export my inbox/outbox to anything readable by Excel (.CSV) I have tweaked an Apple Script which suddenly crashes at the same point (after about 1300 emails are exported) and returns the error message

> error "Mail got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609

My code is:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set LinkRemoval to make new workbook
    set theSheet to active sheet of LinkRemoval
    set value of range "D1" of theSheet to "Message"
    set value of range "C1" of theSheet to "Subject"
    set value of range "B1" of theSheet to "From"
    set value of range "A1" of theSheet to "Date"
end tell

with timeout of (30 * 60) seconds -- timeout set to 30 mins --
    tell application "Mail"
        set theRow to 2
        set theAccount to "Gmail"
        get account theAccount
        set theMessages to messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Gmail"
        -- target mailbox for extracting to excel--
        repeat with aMessage in theMessages
            my SetDate(date received of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
            my SetFrom(sender of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
            my SetSubject(subject of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
            my SetMessage(content of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
            set theRow to theRow + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe try `launch application "Mail"` followed by `tell application "Mail" to activate`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it seems to have worked itself out. I think it may have been because Mail crashed, but am not sure why it kept on doing so at roughly the same point.